# Windows getting stuck on top in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

I'm noticing an issue where windows will get pinned on top of another in 8.1. This happens completely randomly. I'll bring up a second application, and it won't appear until I actually minimize my Chrome (or other) foreground window. Does anyone know how to fix this?

The only applications I run are OneDrive, f.lux, and puush. I've tried disabling them all and it helps none.

Comment: Not an answer, but a small workaround as I'm stuck with this problem too: If you have the always-on-top window active, pressing `ctrl+alt+esc` will remove the "always on top" state at least momentarily. Restarting `explorer.exe` also seems to temporarily alleviate the problem for me. Hope you get an answer that fixes it.

Comment: see also http://superuser.com/questions/877533/windows-are-acting-as-if-they-are-always-on-top

Comment: Check this answer I've just added to a similar question: [http://superuser.com/a/884255/421833][1]


  [1]: http://superuser.com/a/884255/421833